# Is there an archive of deb.torproject.org?

Tags: debian

Debian's apt repository is archived at http://snapshot.debian.org/. Is there such an archive for http://deb.torproject.org/ as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no snapshot service for deb.tpo.  [archive.tpo](https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/debs/main/t/tor/) has some old .debs but it is not updated regularly, and thus not current.

All source versions can be found in [git](https://gitweb.torproject.org/debian/tor.git) though - the are properly tagged too.  If you need a specific binary build I can probably provide it - I should have all the non-dailies on disk.  (Contact me off-site.)

Answer (score 0):

The Debian snapshot site is a archive for old, no longer needed packages that would be in the main repositories otherwise just wasting space. The tor project still hasn't reach such amount of packages so, a way back machine doesn't exist for the tor project.

As far it can be seen in the repository pool, all the packages since `0.2.3.25-1` are stored there. The `-#` at the end of the version means that the package has been debianized, since there could be mistakes in the packaging that needs to be solved but you can't bump the version of Tor just for that.